# Why do I have Task that last for 10 seconds

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am currently studying TPL and have come up with the very first test that already does not produce the expected output. Is my code wrong or is it the expected result
What puzzle me is the fact that I am starting 20 taks that does nothing but wait and I was expecting the all process to finish in 5s, it takes much more, furthermore I have task that now takes 10 s instead of the 5 expected.

Thanks for the help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3Task
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>((index) =>
                    {
                        var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait();
                        var end = DateTime.UtcNow;
                        return string.Format("start={0}, duration={1} for task={2}", start.TimeOfDay, (end - start).TotalSeconds, index);
                    }, i);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            tasks.ForEach((t) => Console.WriteLine(t.Result));
        }
    }
}
```

and the output is:

```
start=10:07:19.8499784, duration=9,4992059 for task=0
start=10:07:19.8489785, duration=9,5002058 for task=1
start=10:07:19.8499784, duration=9,4992059 for task=2
start=10:07:19.8499784, duration=9,4992059 for task=3
start=10:07:19.8499784, duration=9,4992059 for task=4
start=10:07:19.8489785, duration=9,5002058 for task=5
start=10:07:19.8489785, duration=9,5002058 for task=6
start=10:07:19.8489785, duration=9,5002058 for task=7
start=10:07:20.8481051, duration=5,0016351 for task=8
start=10:07:21.8492322, duration=5,5006984 for task=9
start=10:07:22.8483595, duration=5,5046991 for task=10
start=10:07:23.8494862, duration=5,4996981 for task=11
start=10:07:24.8486135, duration=5,0006344 for task=12
start=10:07:25.8497402, duration=5,0116365 for task=13
start=10:07:25.8507412, duration=5,0106355 for task=14
start=10:07:26.8488675, duration=5,0096356 for task=15
start=10:07:27.3499306, duration=5,0076366 for task=16
start=10:07:27.3499306, duration=5,0076366 for task=17
start=10:07:28.3530586, duration=5,0126368 for task=18
start=10:07:28.3530586, duration=5,0126368 for task=19
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Your tasks take 9.5, 5.5 and 5 seconds. The first 8 are all fired at the same time, but every task after that takes another second to start. Tasks start completing more quickly once that slow trickle of task starts starts.

Comment: Try replacing Task.Delay with Thread.Sleep and see what happens. I'm curious.

Comment: @zmbq I don't think using `Thread.Sleep()` would make any difference. Blocking wait is a blocking wait.

Comment: @zmbq: Using Thread.Sleep actually does. Now it takes excactly 5s to run the task. I think it is related to the fact that the task will not release the thread during that sleep. So it means that the behaviour is less volatile. Is there any way to achieve the same behviour with task ? Should I start new task and waitany to finish then start the next one ? Would it be the correct pattern to have task that last for 5s?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is that the TPL (actually, the Thread Pool) throttles the number of threads that you can create at once. You should not alter this behaviour, since it's to stop loads of threads all being launched at once which can cause issues.

However, it *is* possible to increase the number of threads instantly available in the thread pool by using [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx) like so:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20);
```

You should almost always only do this for test purposes though.

If you try adding that line to the start of your program, it will make it behave as expected.

Also note that the actual delay is coming from this line:

```
Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Wait();
```

The `.Wait()` is causing a threadpool thread to run, and it is being throttled so that it doesn't start immediately.

You can verify this by changing that line to:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Then you'll see that the thread takes 5 seconds even without using `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20);`

Comment: That is a good point and will not try to change the ThreadPool default behaviour. I just try to understand why do I have task that will take 10s. I could have understand that task takes a little bit more than 5s but not 10. I have done the same test for 100 tasks and it takes forever where as all these tasks could have finished roughly 5s after they have been started( all at the same time roughly)

Comment: @Dave Well I tried adding that `SetMinThreads()` line, and it does make the tasks then take 5s each, so I'm sure that's what the problem is.

Comment: @Dave Yes, so it's the fact that you're using `Task.Delay()` which causes another threadpool thread to run, and the creation of that thread is throttled.. If you change it to `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));` you'll see that the thread lasts for 5 seconds instead of 10 even when you don't call `SetMinThreads()`